# Path between two points in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, shortest-path

I have black and white images that look like this:

[image]

I need to check if it is possible to reach one pixel from another using only white pixels and find the path, if possible.

For example, I want to know if I can reach pixel (8, 22) (red) from pixel (41,10) (blue). In this example it is possible, and one possible path is shown below:

[image]

To do that I use a breadth-first-search algorithm that I implemented in Python, but it gets really slow if the path does not exist, because it tries all possible paths.

I want to know if there is an already implemented method that I can use to do that?

I know that there are similar algorithms like floodFill, watershed and distanceTransform (implemented in opencv, scipy and skimage) that are really fast, but don't give me the path I want.

Comment: Look at [Dijkstra's pathfinding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding).

Comment: All 'edges' have weight 1 in my problem, so BFS would give the same result as Dijkstra. Is there an optimized implementation of Dijkstra that I could use? That might work

Comment: Floodfill would solve the problem of checking if the path exists, but how can I get the path from floodfill?

Comment: I'm sure there were more comments on this question before...they have disappeared. Anyway it would be good to know why solutions liek distanceTransform "don't give me the path I want" -- what is the problem with the found path?

Comment: Distance transform gives the distance from the pixel to the border. What I want is different.